# batch: pipe file to another file expanding variables within it - essentially creating a form and expander

Tags: batch-file

I have a `form.txt` file like:

```
My name is %name%
```

I want to pipe the file into another file, expanding the variable like:

```
set name=John
echo form.txt|instance.txt
```

and have `instance.txt` read:

```
My name is John
```

Comment: Change `%name%` by `!name!` in `form.txt` file, put `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at beginning of the Batch file, and show the file via `(for /F "delims=" %%a in (form.txt) do echo %%a) > instance.txt`

Comment: Brilliant - worked like a charm - thank you!